# Is Leonid Shifrin OK these days?

Tags: discussion, missing-person

[His profile](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/81/leonid-shifrin) shows he is last seen more than a week ago. OK, this isn't worth worrying of course, what's really worth worrying is, the site http://mathprogramming-intro.org/ i.e. the website for his book *Mathematica programming: an advanced introduction* is down (sold?) for quite a while (to be precise, at least since 2023.11.8). I've tried e-mail him, but doesn't receive any reply so far.

So I dare to ask: how is he doing? Does anyone know his situation?

If nobody knows, how should we deal with the broken links? (There're so many posts in the main site citing the link. )

Comment: my guess he is not getting your email? He had large post at [community](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3099118?p_p_auth=Jx6b09zo) just little than 2 weeks ago. about "Declaring Package with dependencies in multiples files" which also earned **Featured Contributor Badge** there,  but yes, it is strange his book website seems to have gone. May be he forgot to update the yearly domain name fee for it and someone else bought the domain name.  I do not know.  btw, I like the **missing-person** tag. I hope we do not have to use it too  much here.

Comment: I think he's ok. The reason the website is down was multifold but not deliberate from what I know. And one of reasons why hosting wasn't renewed is that the PDF version is available online. So if you know a stable url for the pdf you can replace it.

Comment: @Nasser The post at the community was done under my name, but actually not by me. It was done by me colleagues at WRI, of course with my consent.

Comment: Sorry, but is creating a new tag necessary?

Comment: @TymaGaidash AFAIK this is the third question in this category in MMA.SE. (One of them is deleted, though: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2614/1871 ) So, why not? :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I am all right, just less active on the site these days. Thanks for the concerns though, I am flattered :) . Thanks also to [@Kuba](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) for pinging me. I will make a note to maybe increase my presence on the site, if / when I can afford it timewise.

With the site, it is a different story. Because of well-known events, it became much more cumbersome to maintain it for me, since I can no longer directly send payments (hosting etc.) to places outside Russia. That overlapped with certain personal circumstances, and the hosting service subscription wasn't renewed in time, which is admittedly rather unfortunate. At some point in the future I will look into revamping the site / web version of the book, but it is hard to predict when that will happen.

Comment: Happy to know you're alright :) .

Comment: Isn't there an organization—well known around here—that might host this at no costs for you (to say the least...)? ;-)

Comment: @gwr Perhaps. Something to think about. Costs are not a problem, I just have no direct means to pay them easily. But thanks for the suggestion :)